# How to detect state of aws instance from inside of itself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have auto scaling group in EC2 and I want to detect the state of the instance when it is getting terminated, so that I could start exporting log files before it will be terminated.

I know a way to do this is use autoscaling lifecycle hooks but from my understanding I would have to use external monitor which would then have to ssh into instance and do the export of log files. Ideally I would like to find a way on how to detect state of instance from inside (when the auto scaling group sends command to terminate it) so it would do the export on its own without communicating with any other instances. Anyone would know if its possible to do this, if so where could I begin?

Comment: After I've spent some time on this I have realised that I can detect state of instance by using `aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id XXXX` but this would detect actual state of instance and not the autoscaling lifecycle hook state which I was hoping for. So I have taken the path recommended by John and will use SNS notifications to lambda and from lambda I'll make a call to instances.

Comment: why involve Lambda? can SNS directly post a message via HTTP/S to your instance? or do you not have a webserver running. Just asking because I'm trying to determine if I need to involve Lambda.

Comment: There is an endpoint you can curl, but it doesn't seem to have state :( http://169.254.169.254/latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but this might work...

The lifecycle hook can send a notification to **SNS**. This could then send a message to an **HTTP Endpoint**, which could be a web application you have running on the server. The application could then perform the shutdown activities you desire.

Comment: This would use "external" ways to solve my problem. Which I'm trying to avoid. I came up with an idea of detecting state of my instance from inside and then exporting log files. Haven't tested this yet but will see how it goes..

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution, inspired by your idea of checking status...

**Get the instance ID**

`http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

**Get the instance's Lifecycle State**

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-instances --instance-ids <instance-id>
```

It returns something like:

```
{
  "AutoScalingInstances": [
      {
          "InstanceId": "i-4ba0837f",
          "HealthStatus": "HEALTHY",
          "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2c",
          "AutoScalingGroupName": "my-auto-scaling-group",
          "LifecycleState": "InService"
      }
  ]
}
```

If Lifecycle Hooks are activated, the `LifecycleState` field would be `Pending:Wait` when it is being terminated. This would be the signal for your application to shutdown, export log files, etc.

**Signal readiness to terminate**

Once the application has finished its termination activities, it could signal its readiness to be terminated. This could be done via:

- Defining a heartbeat value when creating the lifecycle hook, after which the instance is automatically terminated
- Extending the heartbeat during the shutdown process (see below)
- When ready to shutdown, stop sending the heartbeat

The heartbeat call would be:

```
aws autoscaling record-lifecycle-action-heartbeat --lifecycle-hook-name my-lifecycle-hook --instance-id my-instance
```

In total, the above steps should allow an instance to detect its own state and signal its own readiness to be terminated. (Although, to be accurate, the 'signal' is actually the 'absence' of a signal to keep running.

Comment: Requires that you can run aws inside of the instance. It would be nice if there was a way to do this without the aws command.

Comment: @NorseGaud You can use an AWS SDK with your preferred programming language instead of the AWS CLI. The OP's desire was to detect the state from _within_ the instance, so some form of call to the EC2 service is required, either via an SDK or the CLI.

Comment: I have a need to not include any secrets inside of the instance since we're turning it into an AMI that'll be public. :(

Comment: @NorseGaud Agreed. Secrets should never be stored on an instance. Instead, **assign an IAM Role** to the instance, which will automatically provide the necessary credentials to use the AWS CLI, without storing any secrets on the instance.