# How to trigger/capture an event in nodejs before AWS EC2 instance get terminate

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

We have nodejs running environment in AWS EC2 with auto scale.

When load is increased/decreased auto scale get triggered. Here we want to trigger/capture an event in nodejs before AWS instance get terminate (because of scale down) to execute some code in nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to add a [Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hook](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) to the autoscaling group.  By adding an `EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING` hook, your instance moves from from the `Terminating` state to the `Terminating:Wait` state. After you complete the lifecycle action, the instances enter the `Terminating:Proceed` state. When the instances are fully terminated, they enter the `Terminated` state.

During the `Terminating:Wait` state you can run the NodeJS process.

There are different ways to notify the instance that is has entered the `Terminating:Wait` state.  There is a good discussion of those options here:
[How to detect state of aws instance from inside of itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914004/how-to-detect-state-of-aws-instance-from-inside-of-itself)

See [Auto Scaling Lifecycle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/AutoScalingGroupLifecycle.html)